# How to change the default script when entering the site

Tags: javascript, html, css

First, I would like to apologize for my English.

I have a script that when clicking on the fa-icon, it opens a description.

My problem is, when I enter the site, it is already open.

I need that when entering the site, it is closed for me to click on the button and it opens.

```
                <script>
                    function convertDate(e) {
                        var t, o = new Date(e);
                        return [(t = o.getDate(), t < 10 ? "0" + t : t)].join("/")
                    }
                    function getMesExtenso(e) {
                        var t = new Array(12);
                        return t[0] = "janeiro", t[1] = "fevereiro", t[2] = "março", t[3] = "abril", t[4] = "maio", t[5] = "junho", t[6] = "julho", t[7] = "agosto", t[8] = "setembro", t[9] = "outubro", t[10] = "novembro", t[11] = "dezembro", t[e]
                    }
                    jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
                        var t = new Date,
                            o = t.setDate(t.getDate() - 11),
                            n = t.setDate(t.getDate() + 18),
                            r = getMesExtenso(t.getMonth());
                        if (convertDate(o) > convertDate(n)) var a = "<strong>" + convertDate(n) + "</strong> e <strong>" + convertDate(o) + " de " + r + "</strong>";
                        else {
                            if (null == (s = getMesExtenso(t.getMonth() + 1))) var s = getMesExtenso(t.getMonth() - 11);
                            a = "<strong>" + convertDate(n) + " de " + r + "</strong> e <strong>" + convertDate(o) + " de " + s + "</strong>"
                        }
                        e.getJSON("https://wtfismyip.com/json", function(t) {
                            var o = (t = t.YourFuckingLocation).replace(", Brazil", "");
                            e(".custom-address").html(" <span class='text-shipping' style='color: #404040; font-family: Roboto,sans-serif; font-weight: 500; color: #727272; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;'>Entrega via Correios© <span class='text-shipping d-block' style='margin-top: -1px; font-size:9.3px;'><span style='color:#59c00b; '>FRETE GRÁTIS</span> PARA " + o + " e região</font></strong></span> ");
                            e(".shipping-preview-loading").hide();
                            e("#deliverygarante").html("Estimada entre " + a + "."), e(".shipping-preview-loading").hide();
                        })
                        
                        $(".shipping-preview-line").click(function () {
          
              
            $("#content-collapse").toggle( "slow", function() {
              // Animation complete.
            
            
            var arrow_mode = $("#arrow--delivery").attr("data-open");
          
              if($("#arrow--delivery").attr("data-open") == "false") {
                
              $("#arrow--delivery").attr("data-open", "true");
          
              $("#arrow--delivery").html('<i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>');
            
              }else if($("#arrow--delivery").attr("data-open") == "true") {
              $("#arrow--delivery").attr("data-open", "false");
              $("#arrow--delivery").html('<i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>');
              }
          
                
            
            console.log("Animation completed");
            });
          });
                    });
          
          
          </script>
```

[image: FA-ICON BUTTON]
[image: when entering the site]
[image: what do i want to see when i enter the site]

I tried several things and 0 results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matheus, I meant - your problem is that you only handle the behavior on click and not anywhere else, so while first opening the site there's no click, and data-attr is true by default, so you need to set it to false at the beginning.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems so me, that you compare `false` value with `== "false"` and so with `true` is a problem, as i remember JQuery gives you here real boolean automatically after data-attr reading

Comment: Upon entering the site (open)
<span data-open="false"
button <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>

By clicking on the description button
<span data-open="true"
<i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>

I noticed that it is inverted, but I cannot change the pattern when entering the site.

Comment: website error > https://www.ondeacha.com.br/products/barber-pro-max

Comment: Your open-close handler connected only to click, of course, i don't see the processing here on opening, `document.ready` does not have any thing for that

Comment: What do I need to send you for you to help me? I have a version that is working on another domain

Comment: Answered below.